# Windows 10 not able to remove read only atttribute of the folders

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-10-upgrade, read-only

I have tried all the solutions listed under the [windows-10] tag on superuser.

The folder that I am trying to change attribute is "E:/myFolder". This folder is created by me.

I am not able to revert the `read only` attributes of the folders on my Windows 10 Laptop.
All the folders that I have/created are having `read-only (Only applies to files in folder)` enabled. This is causing issues for some of the applications that I have, applications are failing to write to the folder.

I have tried all the solutions found on google:

1. attrib -r -s E:\MyFolder
2. I have Controlled Access Disabled
3. I am the owner of the folder and the drive
4. I am the Administrator of the system I have full access

The only thing that failed (from all the solutions that I tried) is when I try to select the check box `replace all child object permission entries with inheritable` when I select this box for my drive and select Apply I get an error `Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.`

Also, sometimes while trying the above steps I get a corrupt Recycle Bin error and Windows asks me to empty it.

**I have followed the below links, and solutions provided in the links:**

1. https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/13392-how-to-fix-folders-reverting-to-read-only-on-windows-10
2. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/read-only-folders-by-default-following-windows-10/da38ac2b-cce6-4ecd-9515-cd22e41fe49f
3. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/read-only-folders-by-default-following-windows-10/da38ac2b-cce6-4ecd-9515-cd22e41fe49f
4. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/all-folders-are-now-read-only-windows-10/0ca1880f-e997-46af-bd85-042a53fc078e
5. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/read-only-folders-by-default-following-windows-10/da38ac2b-cce6-4ecd-9515-cd22e41fe49f?page=2

I have AntiVirus installed and no threat detected so far.
I have diagnosed my drives for Hardware failures or corruptions and all are ok, no issue found.
I have tried all the fixes other than formatting the system and installing new.

If it is a new feature then it is causing the problem to save files in a folder.
Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: What specific folders are you trying to change? Some are restricted and you cannot change them. Edit your question in the early part to describe the names of the folders you are trying to change.

Comment: The folder you created should work. Make sure it is not part of My Documents on Drive C: .  Otherwise try using a different Windows User ID to test that way.

Comment: Are you sure that the disk is in good shape? Have you tried it on another computer? What model is the disk?

Comment: Disk is good it is Segate, I have run multiple test to check if any issue with disk

Comment: I have only two users one is admin and one is my personal account with admin access

Comment: Make a new Admin user and try that.

Comment: Boot to WinRE and do the ACL change from there, else enable the default `Administrator` account, and try from there, remembering to _disable_ the default `Administrator` account once done as it should never be left enabled for security reasons.

Comment: I need a permanent solution on this issue, I don't want to boot every time in some different environment to change the permission

Comment: Try to change the permissions while booting into Safe mode, then reboot it into Safe mode. Do the permissions stay?

Comment: Likely the issue is that E:\ is not always available (e.g., external HDD that takes time to spin up), *not* that there's a back box [not checkmark!] under read-only property. It is normal for all folders to be in that third state, and Windows ignores a folder's read-only status.

Comment: I did try with safe mode and also E: is a partition of my HDD and it is not a removable drive. I did try everything but still not able to change the state to non-read only. I am not sure if formatting and reinstalling Windows will solve this problem.