# windows 10 does not allow me to remove the read only checkbox in the properties of a directory

Tags: windows-10, permissions, read-only

**windows 10 does not allow me to remove the read only checkbox in the properties of a directory.**

Hi guys; I am learning programming, and I have encountered a problem that is related to the operating system and not to the programming, just to put them in context:

to program in php using symfony v5.3; requires being able to put write permissions to a specific folder ...

the related directory is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\p1\paguelofacil/var/cache/dev`

this directory exists; you have the necessary users and the users have the read and write permissions; the problem is that no matter how much I try to change the read-only check-box it persists ...

I have tried everything that this other post says and I have not found a solution; even I do not receive any errors ... and in the post I do mention if there is an error ...

[Windows 10 not able to remove read only atttribute of the folders](https://superuser.com/questions/1657909/windows-10-not-able-to-remove-read-only-atttribute-of-the-folders)

even run the following command if no result ...

```
attrib -r C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\p1\paguelofacil\var\*.* /s
```

If more information is needed, do not hesitate to request it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Update:***

To rule out that it is a user permissions problem or that it is a problem with the php script I have done the following:

1. I have placed a patch (PHP) where I correct the write permission in the directory:

```
    echo 'Directory Exist '. $dir .'<br>';
    echo get_current_user().'<br>';
    echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($dir)), -4).'<br>';
    chmod ($dir, 755);
```

Output:

[image]

result of this: solve the problem in a bad way ...

if the user does not have the necessary permissions; PHP would have thrown a ***fatal error!*** with this patch the error is removed but it is not the correct thing.

This is not correct because I should not change permissions from my code ... it is assumed that the permissions must be on the properties and attributes of the directory.

if I remove the patch then the error will come up again; this tells me that it does not matter if I put the attribute or permission; this is lost ...

---

***Let's clarify the following:*** in order to create files (any format) within a directory, we programmers must validate that within that directory we can write ... in Linux the directory must have at least 755 permissions; so I ask you where I can do something similar with Windows?

when we validate a directory, with `is_writable` if the directory has permissions `0555` it will spit out a false (you cannot write to this directory); this permission is general; It is not associated with any user; In linux it is validated that the user / group is the owner of the directory too ... but I have already established this in windows it is assumed that by giving permissions to ***everyone***, I am giving access to all users ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The particular field is weird. The property only applies to the files, so unless the file you have created is read only, your issue is with the code itself failing improperly. Your screenshots don't indicate which user owns the folder "C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\p1\paguelofacil\var\", if you still suspect a permission problem, I guarantee you it's the incorrect user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131919/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That checkbox is not a status indicator, it's a tri-state switch. The select state is applied when the `OK` or `Apply` button is clicked

The three states are:

- **Checked**: Set `ReadOnly` attribute for all files within the folder
- **Cleared**: Clear `ReadOnly` attribute for all files within folder
- **Gray Square**: Take no action (Default on dialog display)

It's just extremely poor UI design, as the `Hidden` checkbox is *both* switch and status indicator.

The only accurate way to determine the status of the `ReadOnly` attribute for folders is to add the `Attributes` column to a `Details` view in **File Explorer**.

[image]

Be aware the attribute does not affect read/write permissions for the folder or its contents. For directories, it functions as a flag that tells Windows to process the folder's `desktop.ini` file (Custom folder icons, localizeed display names, and other custom behavior).

---

---

Check effective permissions on the folder via the `Advanced` dialog accessed from the `Security` tab of the `Properties` dialog:

[image]

Select the `Effective Access` tab and then a user:

[image]

Then select `View effective access`:

[image]

Comment: which column of status ... there are like 15 options ... can you give more details in the answer?

Comment: `echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/tmp')), -4);` It is not clear to me what you say, I have validated the permissions from the script and this is persistent; with this rule out that it is a problem of the script the result is a 0555; then I run: `chmod ($ dir, 755);`

Comment: if the user does not have permission to change this data; I would get a Fatal Error in PHP ...

Comment: the problem then is that I shouldn't change this using the code ... this should be able to be placed in the directory ...

Comment: but if I remove the patch that I have put on it ... it reissues the error ... then what is happening that once the permission attribute is set it is lost ... because if I have not changed anything ...

Comment: Screenshot added. I only have one choice for a column labeled `Attributes`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with your code, but ***Don't waste time worrying about the gray square!***

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Already specified in my answer: "Be aware the attribute does not affect read/write permissions for the folder or its contents...."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131923/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-keith-miller).